# mediaMatch doesn't work (a strange case)

Tags: javascript, media-queries

```
//version 1
var status = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 800px)");
if (status.matches)
{
    document.getElementsByClassName("row")[0].style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
//version 2
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 800px)").matches)
{
    document.getElementsByClassName("row")[0].style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```

I think the two versions would function the same yet the first version won't work while the second will. Anyone can enlighten me why? Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea why the 1st won't work but this make my eyes bleed.
Please put this in CSS and add a classes in JS, not style.

Comment: it works for me. A few things to check: What browser are you using? Have you tried it in other browsers? Have you tried using the dev tools to debug it -- eg `console.log(status);` `console.log(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 800px)").matches);`?